# Why I Cannot access eclipse download site from docker container (connection refused)?

Tags: docker, eclipse, oomph

I am trying to install eclipse inside a docker container (Ubuntu 22.04, JDK 17)
I am trying to use the oomph installer to install the eclipse. Seems like some of the eclipse download sites cant be accessed.

Errors like:

```
!MESSAGE Connection to https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-03/202301131000/p2.index failed on Connect to https://download.eclipse.org:443 [download.eclipse.org/198.41.30.199] failed: Connection refused

!MESSAGE Connection to https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest/compositeContent.jar failed on Connect to https://download.eclipse.org:443 [download.eclipse.org/198.41.30.199] failed: Connection refused. Retry attempt 0 started

!MESSAGE Connection to https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest/compositeArtifacts.jar failed on Connect to https://download.eclipse.org:443 [download.eclipse.org/198.41.30.199] failed: Connection refused. Retry attempt 0 started

!MESSAGE Connection to https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2023-03/202301121200/features/org.eclipse.epp.package.common.feature_4.27.0.20230112-0751.jar failed on Connect to https://download.eclipse.org:443 [download.eclipse.org/198.41.30.199] failed: Connection refused. Retry attempt 0 started

!MESSAGE Connection to https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2023-03/202301121200/features/org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature_4.27.0.20230112-0751.jar failed on Connect to https://download.eclipse.org:443 [download.eclipse.org/198.41.30.199] failed: Connection refused. Retry attempt 0 started

!MESSAGE Failure reporting download statistics to URL: https://download.eclipse.org/stats/technology/epp/packages/2023-03-M1/org.eclipse.epp.package.common/4.27.0.20230112-0751

!MESSAGE Unable to connect to repository https://download.eclipse.org/stats/technology/epp/packages/2023-03-M1/org.eclipse.epp.package.common/4.27.0.20230112-0751

!MESSAGE Connection to https://eclipse.mirror.rafal.ca/releases/2023-03/202301131000/plugins/org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.asciidoc.ui_3.0.42.202201072301.jar failed on Connect to https://eclipse.mirror.rafal.ca:443 [eclipse.mirror.rafal.ca/207.210.46.249] failed: Connection refused. Retry attempt 0 started
```

But these URLs I can access on the host machine. Inside docker container I cannot access them. Furthermore, I can access and download many other files from inside docker container like jdk from oracle, oomph installer file, eclipse tar file etc.

Why this error?

Comment: https://www.eclipsestatus.io/ - _Core Services_ shows also no outages of download.eclipse.org this year.

Comment: Is this at work?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  - no not at work

Comment: @manumuraleedharan First of all, why install Eclipse in a docker container when it runs nicely under Ubuntu itself?  Second, Docker creates a lot of extra networking to handle the various scenarios supported.  This might interfere with the configuration of the network you are using to access the internet giving results like this.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen we are trying to run the docker container as "webtop" as in providing a GUI app inside the container, running in kube8

Comment: Can you replicate this in a freshly installed Ubuntu? Does it work on other locations? Any reason you just don’t download and unzip a non-oomph distribution?